# InfluxDB Insert data using curl - Field format error

Tags: api, curl, influxdb

Getting below error while inserting data.

```
 curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=nagflux' --data-binary 'metrics,host=server1,service=Linux CPU check,command=check_Linux value=2.87 1505131200'
```

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json
Request-Id: 95e6a324-3d69-11e8-b00f-000000000000
X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
X-Influxdb-Error: unable to parse 'metrics,host=server1,service=Linux CPU check,command=check_Linux value=2.87 1505131200': invalid field format
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.4.2
X-Request-Id: 95e6a324-3d69-11e8-b00f-000000000000
Date: Wed, 11 Apr 2018 09:20:33 GMT
Content-Length: 141

{"error":"unable to parse 'metrics,host=server1,service=Linux CPU check,command=check_Linux value=2.87 1505131200': invalid field format"}

Answer (score 2):

Found that Error due to space in the tag value service=Linux CPU check.Correct format is

curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=nagflux' --data-binary 'metrics,host=server1,service=**Linux\ CPU\ check**,command=check_Linux value=2.87 1505131200'

Comment: Hello Madhanika, 

can you please tell me what I am missing here 

echo -e “usage,host=influxdb,cluster=louis,pl_instance_name=2i-retegas,gitlabusage=“Thu Oct 20 13:48:02 2022”,jenkinsusage=“Fri Jan 20 06:52:05 2023”,sonarqubeusage=“Mon Oct 17 11:52:20 2022”,nexususage=“Not Use 00 00:00:00 0000” lastused=averagetime” | curl -X POST --data-binary @- https://influxdb-.com/write?db=usage

I tried everything to resolve but no luck